# Python Tkinter: Updating Label by different StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple line where you are supposed to enter the beginning time of your break, and it should automatically return the endtime. For that purpose, I created a `stringvar` for the entry and a `stringvar` for the `endtime` label.

But no matter what I do, I can't get the `endTime` `Label` to update.

The following code is one of many ways I tried to update the label, but I think I'm missing something more elementary.

Here is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
breakOne = tk.StringVar(self,'08:00')
EndOne = tk.StringVar(self)
CalcEndBreak(EndOne, breakOne.get(), varBreaks.get(), breaksList)

labelBreakOne = tk.Label(self, text="first break:")
entryBreakOne = tk.Entry(self, width = 20, textvariable=breakOne)
labelEndOne = tk.Label(self, textvariable= EndOne)

def CalcEndBreak(Var, start, breakNum, breaksList):
    if breakNum == breaksList[0]:
            try:
                EndTimeOne = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M').time()) + timedelta(minutes= 30)
                Var.set(EndTimeOne.strftime('%H:%M'))
            except ValueError:
                Var.set('Wrong format, please enter HH:MM')
    else:
            try:
                EndTimeOne = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.strptime(start.get(), '%H:%M').time()) + timedelta(minutes= 15)
                Var.set(EndTimeOne.strftime('%H:%M'))
            except ValueError:
                Var.set('Wrong format, please enter HH:MM')    
    return
```

And for reference a larger view at the code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
from sre_parse import State
import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import END, ttk
from tkinter import font as tkfont

from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd



#Controller
class QualiUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        EndOne = tk.StringVar(self)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        #stack Frames
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, TaskGiver, Anmeldung, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # Same location, top is visible
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def statusWindow(self,textMessage):
        newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self)
        newWindow.geometry("400x50")
        tk.Label(newWindow, text=textMessage).pack()




# Default Window
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Aufgabenübergabe", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Aufgabe abgeben",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("TaskGiver"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Anmelden",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Anmeldung"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

class Anmeldung(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        absty = 5
        abstx = 5

        #Names
        labelName = tk.Label(self, text="Name").grid(column=0, row=0,padx= abstx, pady=absty)
        global NamesList
        variable = tk.StringVar(self)
        variable.set(nameList[1])
        option = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable= variable, values = nameList)
        option.grid(column=1, row=0,padx= abstx, pady=absty)

        #Platznummer
        labelPlatz = tk.Label(self, text="Platz:").grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx= abstx, pady= absty)
        entryPlatz = tk.Entry(self, width = 20).grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx= abstx, pady= absty)

        #Pausen
        breakOne = tk.StringVar(self,'08:00')
        breakTwo = tk.StringVar(self,'')

        labelNumPause =  tk.Label(self, text="Pausenart:").grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx= abstx, pady= absty)
        breaksList = ['30 Min.','2x 15 Min.']
        varBreaks= tk.StringVar(self, breaksList[0])
        breaksOption= tk.OptionMenu(self, varBreaks, *breaksList).grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx= abstx, pady= absty)

        EndOne = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.CalcEndBreak(EndOne, breakOne.get(), varBreaks.get(), breaksList)
        EndTwo = tk.StringVar(self)

        breakOne.trace("w", self.CalcEndBreak(EndOne, breakOne.get(), varBreaks.get(), breaksList))

        labelBreakOne = tk.Label(self, text="Erste Pause:")
        entryBreakOne = tk.Entry(self, width = 20, textvariable=breakOne)
        labelEndOne = tk.Label(self, textvariable=EndOne)
        labelBreakTwo = tk.Label(self, text="Zweite Pause:")
        entryBreakTwo = tk.Entry(self, width = 20, textvariable=breakTwo)
        labelEndTwo = tk.Label(self, textvariable= EndTwo, state='normal')

        labelBreakOne.grid(column = 0, row = 3, padx= abstx, pady= absty)
        entryBreakOne.grid(column = 1, row = 3, padx= abstx, pady= absty)
        labelEndOne.grid(column = 2, row = 3, padx= abstx, pady= absty)
        labelBreakTwo.grid(column = 0, row = 4, padx= abstx, pady= absty)
        entryBreakTwo.grid(column = 1, row = 4, padx= abstx, pady= absty)
        labelEndTwo.grid(column = 2, row = 4, padx= abstx, pady= absty)



        BOK = tk.Button(self, text="Ok",
                            command=lambda: [controller.show_frame("PageTwo"), controller.statusWindow("Erfolgreich Übermittelt")]).grid(column=0, row=8, pady=absty)
        BAbbr = tk.Button(self, text="Abbrechen",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")).grid(column=1, row=8,pady= absty)

def getNames(file):
    dfNames = pd.read_excel(file,'Sheet1', header=0)
    dfNames = dfNames["Mitarbeiter"]
    dfNames = dfNames.drop_duplicates()
    return dfNames.tolist()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Namesfile = r"C:\Users\...\names.xlsx"
    nameList = getNames(Namesfile)
    #print(namelist)
    app = QualiUI()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete and executable example of your code? My current guess is that you are only calling your `CalcEndBreak` function once at the start of the program before the user has entered any data and then never again.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: I can imagine thats probably the reason. I updated the question to give more context.
I'm calling the function within the class instance i created for that particular frame.
Apologies if that's obvious, but how should i call the function for it to update with the loop?